# Is the Typhoon supposed to kill robots on hard difficulty?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm playing Deus Ex Human Revolution on the Give Me Deus Ex difficulty.

The description of Typhoon's level two upgrade is: `Deals enough damage to kill any enemy, including all robot types.`

I'm using it now for the first time in the hanger bay in Hengsha where there are two heavy robots. I run right up to the robot's face, and then activate it, and then the robot is not apparently damaged in any way. I literally can't even tell if it's damaging them.

Is the description inaccurate, or am I encountering a bug?

I've tried this like 5 times now, and I've confirmed that I have the Typhoon system fully upgraded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those large robots are exceptional mini-bosses, and only appear in set-piece fights. Therefore, they are not subject to the instant death rule from Typhoon blasts. However, the Typhoon should still do very high damage to them. iirc, two blasts should be a kill.

Comment: Agreed, Typhoon won't one shot *everything* even when fully upgraded, but it will do a pretty decent amount of damage.

Comment: Isn't an EMP grenade a /much/ quicker solution?

Comment: If you have them, EMP grenades are the best option, yep. But Typhoons are fast as well. Like I said, about 2 shots of Typhoon. So not a lot quicker to use EMPs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you bought the product from Steam? Then there is a chance that a patch has been applied.

I have played Deus Ex: Human Revolution on every difficulty level, and in each case the 'highest' level of Typhoon was enough to kill ***ANY*** bot, however large they may be.

This is not a fantasy - because the internet is full of Youtube videos where you can kill Namir with one punch. In my version, it is not possible - if you try to knock him out, there is a kind of shield which comes around him to prevent that.

So my best guess is that patches are applied to change parts of the game.

P.S I intended this as a comment, but don't have the reputation to make one. It will be disappointing to receive downvotes just because people may not have observed the same behavior.

Answer (score -1):

depending on the augmentation then yes